# Tack Image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, webcam

In my web application i loaded camera using webcam.js when open camera it displays adobe flash player setting dialog box for user accept or deny. I want to open camera with out asking to user(without dialog). Please help me.

Comment: That's called voyuerism.

Answer (score 1):

Happily, this is impossible. A user visiting a website is not sufficient indication that they trust that website to access their camera.

If you want to access webcams without their owners' permission, then go and [work in the intelligence community](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/feb/27/gchq-nsa-webcam-images-internet-yahoo).